# How can I change image background on hover when clicking accordion?

Tags: html, css, elementor

I want to change the image next to the accordion when toggling/clicking the accordion items. 
I am sorry I can't provide any code because I just don't know where to start... Thanks in advance!
My site is: https://aviel-albo.com/services/ 
The site is in Hebrew, in case you ask yourself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<html>
<body>

<img onmouseover="otherImg(this)" onmouseout="normalImg(this)" border="0" src="https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/client/q_glossy,ret_img/https://aviel-albo.com/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/jordan-whitt-145327-unsplash-min-o7d1qu5enzt7olvmxk54flz05g93601jl1mzty5e78.jpg" width="132" height="132">

<p>The function otherImg() is triggered when the user moves the mouse pointer over the image.</p>
<p>The function normalImg() is triggered when the mouse pointer is moved out of the image.</p>

<script>
function otherImg(x) {
  x.src = "https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif";
 
}

function normalImg(x) {
  x.src = "https://cdn.shortpixel.ai/client/q_glossy,ret_img/https://aviel-albo.com/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/jordan-whitt-145327-unsplash-min-o7d1qu5enzt7olvmxk54flz05g93601jl1mzty5e78.jpg";
  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! but I meant to change the image when toggling the accordion options. not when hovering the image.